# Getting an error while trying to read CSV files through HDFS with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, hdfs, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to read a csv file located in my hdfs filesystem through apoc library in Neo4j with the following line of code"

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('hdfs://ipAddrress:port/myFileLocation.csv')
```

I also disabled Neo4j configuration for apoc and enabled importing files through apoc. So i included the following lines in my configuration file:

```
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

but i keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.csv`: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream
```

The dependencies are built into neo4j apoc extension but i don't know why the hadoop-related class can't be found. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet a bit, I found this from Tom Geudens.

> At this time that is not possible : CSV files can be stored on the
> database server and are then accessible using a file:/// URL.
> Alternatively, LOAD CSV also supports accessing CSV files via HTTPS,
> HTTP, and FTP.
> You may be able to expose your hdfs filesystem over http (and then use
> a http:// url) but otherwise ... no.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible by querying through Neo4j directly, but i'm trying to use apoc library which according to https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/import/web-apis/ supports csv read/write from/to hdfs.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this before. Best to create an issue on github: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures and the guys can fix this.